# Craft 3 doesn't translate static strings

Tags: localization

I am making a website with Craft 3 and I have some static text that needs to be translated.

I followed Craft's documentation on it. I created my `translations/fr/site.php` file and use the `{{ 'String'|t }}` format to translate my strings.

I tried everything I found on the web, but I can not make it work. My strings stay in english and doesn't translate. It doesn't even seem to access the `site.php` file.

I tried to clear my cache, restart my Docker container, change the folder name to `fr-CA` instead of `fr` ...

I found another member here that had the same problem as me, but he updated Craft and it worked. My Craft configuration is up to date...

Is there something I am missing?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you get in an incognito window?

Comment: Have you tried copying a working translation's English string and "statically" translating it in it's stead to check if that works? 
---
Example: `{{ welcome_message|t }}` let's say `welcome_message` is `Welcome User!` so you replace the dynamic reference as follows `{{ 'Welcome User!'|t }}`
---
If that works but your other static translations don't, then there's an error with your input string or your translation array having the wrong text as key.

Comment: Hi, I did try with an incognito windows and it didn't work. And I don't use dynamic reference, I simply use plain static strings.

Answer (score 2):

I'm simply trying to follow the [docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/static-translations.html#provide-the-translations) as good as possible.

### Try the following:

#### Example String we'll be using: `"cheese"` | `"fromage"`

1. in your `config/general.php` make sure you have your `siteUrl` set as an array with at least two entries, example:`'siteUrl' => ['my_site_en' => 'http://localhost:1234, 'my_site_fr => 'http://localhost:1234/fr/'];`
2. in your `translations/fr/site.php` make sure it only contains the following

   ```
   <?php

   return [
     'cheese' => 'fromage',
   ];
   ```
3. in your twig file add the following `<h1>{{ "cheese"|t }}</h1>`

4. **important**: Access your Control Panel (`cpTrigger` in `config/general.php` for the first part of the URL), => `http://localhost:1234/%CP_TRIGGER%/settings/sites` and make sure you have **2 sites, both in the same group, one in `en`, one in `fr` & their URLs must also be set!**  
 It should look similar to this [image: Craft CP with two sites, main english, additional french]

As long as all 4 steps are followed, it **should** work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was seriously hoping this would work, but it didn't. I seriously don't know what I am doing wrong, but it is genuinely frustrating!

Comment: Alright well let's not give up just quite yet, we still have a few things we can try...

clear your logs `storage/logs/*` and then call an URL which *should* (if it worked) translate a string to another language.

After that please zip your entire `storage/logs` folder and upload it to some file-sharing website and post the link in the comments so I can take a look at it, I think that'd be a good place to check as the logs sometimes have some info which may get overlooked otherwise. (For example you could use https://send.firefox.com/)

Comment: Hi Campiotti. Here are the logs files: https://send.firefox.com/download/49de7f59e66f4879/#bm3SAgphYcNqYAG4yThKtA

The two lines I'm trying to translate are called "Email Address" and "Go!" in case it helps you find something.

Comment: Oh I forgot about the time-limit on the send.firefox.com downloads sorry!
I miseed the download span and am now unable to download the logs... I think it might be better if a more non-temporary file hoster would be used like https://mediafire.com . Sorry about that, but could you please upload the logs once more but to that file hoster? Then the link wouldn't expire so fast and I'll try and take a look at the logs to see if I can find anything, thanks.

Comment: There you go: http://www.mediafire.com/file/8zkvrlzi2na9mvx/logs.zip/file

Comment: I searched your logs and I wasn't able to find any occurrences of `Email Address` or `Go!` nor did I find any warnings or errors... so long your translations are in a file that should've been loaded, such as `home.twig`, I'm really not sure what could be the cause of this not functioning....


BUT I have *one more thing for you to try*: [This Craft3 Free Translations Plugin](https://github.com/jan-dh/translator#readme) This allows managing/translating static translated strings from your templates directly in the Control-Panel. 
I hope this works/fixes it.

Comment: Hi Campiotti, thank you so much for your help. My problem did get solved! When I deployed my site to a web server, it worked. I can't make it work on localhost tho.

Comment: strange... glad that it works on your deployed site though!

Not sure if they'd be able to fix it but maybe make a bug report on the craft cms 3 github issues page, this might be a bug or it might be some misconfigured aspect of your local installation which isn't present on the deployed server.